# Include Rich text web part in document template

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-library, list-item, rich-text

I have a workflow which creates a word document in document library, when a new item is created in list. The list has a rich text field. The document is created successfully with all the contents but the rich text field displays text within **HTML tags**. Is there a way to include **rich text content** in word documents?

The document is created with the help of this blog: http://blogs.technet.com/b/brenclarke/archive/2009/04/15/automatically-create-word-documents-which-include-list-fields.aspx

**Update**

I am using SharePoint Online 2013.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As per your link I assumed that you have done following process.

you have created column in your list and same column you have added in the document library.

that means you have created Multi Line of text(with rich text) site column and added same column to list as well as library and you are creating document from template(in template you have added document properties) using SharePoint Designer Workflow.

So the main problem is RichText Field(multi line of text with Rich Text) is not supported in document library.

See below links

1. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/67a70245-cd03-48e1-b0fa-71bbb6a7744d/is-enhanced-rich-text-column-supported-by-document-library?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy
2. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/95a05ae0-5d3b-432f-81bf-1f4a03e9910b/rich-text-column-in-document-library?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

So in short you can not achieve your requirement using this way. You need to use OpenXML or other tool to create word file programmatically.

You can get some idea from "https://html2openxml.codeplex.com/documentation"

Hope it will help to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this openxml document be created when a new item is created in a list?

Comment: Yes. but you need create ItemAdded Event receiver for that and in event receiver you can write code to generate word document using OpenXML

Comment: Actually, I don't have an option to write VB.Net code. I'm using SharePoint online 2013.

Comment: Then I don't think that you can achieve this requirement in O365 :(